# Chosen plugin max_selected_options

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

I use [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) jquery plugin and I noticed that **max_selected_options** is not working:

The code is this:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chosen/chosen.css" />
</head>
<body>

<select id="assets" data-placeholder="Choose assets" class="chzn-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
    <option value="e">e</option>
    <option value="f">f</option>
    <option value="g">g</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="chosen/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".chzn-select").chosen();
        $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({allow_single_deselect:true});
        $('.chzn-select').chosen({ max_selected_options: 3 });
        $(".chzn-select").bind("liszt:maxselected", function () { alert("a"); });
        $(".chzn-select").chosen().change( function () { alert("a"); } );
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand what is incorrect to my code. This line:

```
$('.chzn-select').chosen({ max_selected_options: 3 });
```

should limit the maximum number of allowed selections. But it doesn't work. I still can select any number of items.
I noticed that also the event that should be fired on the case the maximum number of selected items is reached doesn't fire:

```
$(".chzn-select").bind("liszt:maxselected", function () { alert("a"); });
```

**Do I have any error in code?**

And one more question: how can I add search functionality to my list, like the search box that appears on the first example on the plugins page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You call twice the `chosen()` method, which is why you get problems:

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen();
$('.chzn-select').chosen({ max_selected_options: 3 });
```

Remove the first one and it works. Your JS code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({allow_single_deselect:true});
    $(".chzn-select").chosen({ max_selected_options: 3 });
    $(".chzn-select").bind("chosen:maxselected", function () { alert("max elements selected"); });
    $(".chzn-select").chosen().change( function () { alert("change"); } );
});
```

Comment: what if we need to alter the max_selected_options latter? that means it will not work, from your explanation

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu The `chosen`plugin does not seem to have the possibility to change the settings after init, so I think the only option is to destroy the plugin and reinitialize it: `$(".chzn-select").chosen("destroy");` then `$(".chzn-select").chosen({ max_selected_options: 5 });`