# Is there a way to limit the amount of selected options in a select that uses jquery chosen?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-chosen

I'm using an template that the company bought, the template uses the following as part of the app.

- Bootstrap v2.3.1
- Chosen v0.9.8 (https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen)
- Select2.js v3.3.2

Also as part the init code of the template this is included:

```
var handleChoosenSelect = function () {
    if (!jQuery().chosen) {
        return;
    }

    $(".chosen").each(function () {
        $(this).chosen({
            allow_single_deselect: $(this).attr("data-with-diselect") === "1" ? true : false
        });
    });
}
```

I have the following code:

```
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span12 ">
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label">Total Sctions</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <select class="span4 select2" id="id_total_section" name="total_section">
                  <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span12">
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label">Section</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <select class="chosen" id="id_section" multiple="multiple" name="section">
                  <option value="1">Value 1 [1]</option>
                  <option value="2">Value 2 [2]</option>
                  <option value="3">Value 3 [3]</option>
                  <option value="4">Value 4 [4]</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

The idea is to dynamically limit the amount of sections selected from the select element.

I aleady did a test trying to limit using this into the code, but I hade no luck, It keeps selecting more than 1 element.

```
    $("#id_section").chosen({ max_selected_options: 1 });
    $("#id_section").chosen().change( function () {
      console.debug("Change done");
    } );
```

Any help to solve this is welcome.

Comment: According to the [chosen documentation](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), `max_selected_options` should work for you. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Hi Rory, No errors in the console has appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a duplicate of [Chosen plugin max_selected_options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382875/chosen-plugin-max-selected-options)

The problem is that you call `$("#id_section").chosen()` right after `$("#id_section").chosen({ max_selected_options: 1 });` which seems to nullify the options.

Comment: I already checked the post that you kindly indicate, however the solution that is stated there, is not working in the my app. The reason for this is because as I indicated there is a template that already has an init section and that section must remain untouched.